# Valgrind -> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Tags: c, valgrind

I do not understand why I'm going to sort this error "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)", while all variables are initialized, including defines them.

```
#include "shell.h"

int     ft_complete_apply_key(t_cmd *cmd)
{
    int     key;

    key = cmd->last_key;
    if (key == KEY_TERM_RIGHT || key == KEY_TERM_LEFT
        || key == KEY_TERM_HOME || key == KEY_TERM_END) // error here
        return (ft_move_cursor(cmd));
    if (key == KEY_TERM_DEL)
        return (ft_complete_apply_del(cmd));
    if (key == KEY_TERM_ENTER)
        return (ft_complete_apply_enter(cmd));
    return (ft_complete_apply_printable(cmd));
}
```

Comment: All of them? Even `cmd`? Are you 100% certain?

Comment: It could be because `cmd` is not pointing to a valid instance of `t_cmd `

Comment: Oops sorry @SombreroChicken, Yes totally filled with values!

Comment: The posted code is using a 'home grown' header file: `shell.h`   We can only guess as to the contents of that file.  Please post the contents of `shell.h`

Comment: what is the definition of: `t_cmd`?   what is the contents of the line pointed to by `*cmd`?  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int ft_interactive_read_key(void)
{
    int     nread;
    char    seq[4];

    while ((nread = read(STDIN_FILENO, &seq[0], 1)) != 1)
    {
        if (nread == -1)
            return (0);
    }
    if (seq[0] == '\x1b')
    {
        if (read(STDIN_FILENO, &seq[1], 1) != 1)
            return (ft_atoi(seq));
        if (read(STDIN_FILENO, &seq[2], 1) != 1)
            return (ft_atoi(seq));
        return (*(int*)seq);
    }
    else
    {
        return (seq[0]);
    }
}
```

I  am told that the error can come from this function apparently. I do not see how it is possible. The result of this function goes in `cmd->last_key = ft_interative_read_key();`

**EDIT:**

Actually it comes from the **seq** array that was not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code you have a line similar to this:

```
var = ft_complete_apply_key( some_command );
```

It is quite likely that `some_command` is not initialized, or any of the other variables from which `some_command` is calculated.

`some_command` becomes `cmd` inside `ft_complete_apply_key` as it is obvious.